# Cannot run Asp.Net Core inside docker linux

Tags: asp.net-core, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm trying to get the ASP.Net Core running inside docker with docker-compose. Here is the `dockerfile` content:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-aspnetcore-runtime AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443


FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-sdk AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["SchoolContact/SchoolContact.csproj", "SchoolContact/"]
RUN dotnet restore "SchoolContact/SchoolContact.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/SchoolContact"
RUN dotnet build "SchoolContact.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "SchoolContact.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS http://+:5000
EXPOSE 5000 80
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "SchoolContact.dll"]
```

And here is the `docker-compose.yml` content:

```
version: '3'

services:
  api:
        image: schoolcontact
        build:
          context: .
          dockerfile: SchoolContact/Dockerfile
        links:
          - db:db
        ports:
          - '5000:5000'
        restart: always
        networks:
          - school
  db:
      image: mysql:5.7
      volumes:
        - ./db:/var/lib/mysql
      restart: always
      environment:
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 123456
        MYSQL_DATABASE: Test
        MYSQL_USER: admin
        MYSQL_PASSWORD: 123456
      networks:
        - school

  phpmyadmin:
        depends_on:
          - db
        image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
        restart: always
        ports:
          - '8080:80'
        environment:
          PMA_HOST: db
          MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 123456 
        networks:
          - school

  reverse-proxy:
        container_name: proxy
        image: nginx
        depends_on:
          - api
        ports:
          - "9090:8080"
        volumes:
          - ./proxy.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
        networks:
          - school

networks:
  school:
volumes:
    db:
       driver: "local"
```

The `proxy.conf`:

```
server {
    listen 8080;

    location / {
      proxy_pass http://api:5000;
    }
}
```

I've tried too many times before posting here and ask for help, I tried to run without `nginx`, expose port or not, so many ways. But I still cannot access the app. My final purpose is to host the app in docker and can access it through URL `http://localhost:5000`. I don't know where I've wrong or missing something else. I really need help with this. Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how mine work, after few weeks of researching (for those have the same issue), add these line in the **Main** method. Also, the **dockerfile** and **docker-compose.yml** should look like below:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    //CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    var host = new WebHostBuilder()
        .UseKestrel()
        .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
        .UseUrls("http://*:9001")
        .UseIISIntegration()
        .UseStartup<Startup>()
        .Build();

    host.Run();
}
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
services:
  api:
        image: schoolcontact
        build:
          context: .
          dockerfile: SchoolContact/Dockerfile
        links:
          - db:db
        ports:
          - 9021:9001
        restart: always
        networks:
          - school
```

**dockerfile**

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-aspnetcore-runtime AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
#EXPOSE 443


FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-sdk AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["SchoolContact/SchoolContact.csproj", "SchoolContact/"]
RUN dotnet restore "SchoolContact/SchoolContact.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/SchoolContact"
RUN dotnet build "SchoolContact.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "SchoolContact.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 9001
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "SchoolContact.dll"]
```